# In Bash, how can a here-document contain a variable and then be stored in a variable?

Tags: bash, variables, heredoc

I have something like the following in a Bash script:

```
URL="${1}"
IFS= read -d '' code << "EOF"
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
page = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("${URL}"))
images = page.findAll('img')
for image in images:
    print(image["src"])
EOF
python <(echo "${code}")
```

How can the way the here-document is defined (e.g. not using `read`)  be changed such that the variable `${URL}` is resolved in the here-document and then the here-document is stored in the variable `${code}`? At present, the here-document is stored in the variable successfully, but the variable in the here-document is not being resolved.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest passing the URL in on `sys.argv` or `os.environ`, rather than substituting into your script -- that way lies code injection vulnerabilities. Think about a `URL` containing `"+__import__('shutil').rmtree('/')+"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove quote from `EOF`:

```
URL="${1}"
IFS= read -d '' code <<EOF
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
page = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("${URL}"))
images = page.findAll('img')
for image in images:
    print(image["src"])
EOF
python <(echo "${code}")
```

As per `man bash`:

> If any characters in word are quoted, the delimiter is the result of
>   quote removal on word, **and the lines in the here-document are not
>   expanded.**

Comment: Answers the bash question as asked (and, for that reason, has my upvote), but results in an application vulnerable to code injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Yes I agree @CharlesDuffy. I don't know python that well to suggest a fix in the script.

Comment: [@anubhava](http://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) Thank you very much for your help on that. For any who want to read the Bash man page section on here-documents, you can use the following command to generate a PDF of the man page: ```man -t bash | ps2pdf - bash.pdf```

Comment: One simple fix would be to `import os` at the beginning of the heredoc, export the value in `URL`, and call `urllib2.urlopen(os.environ['URL'])`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't intend to override or replace the (entirely correct) answer to the literal question given by @anubhava -- that answer is correct, and in cases where the document being substituted into *is not* source code, its usage is entirely appropriate.

---

Substituting variables into code (whether in a heredoc or otherwise) is actually a rather dangerous practice -- you risk running into a cousin of [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Much better is to send the variable out-of-band in such a way as to prevent any possibility of parsing as code. In awk, this is done with `-vkey=val`; for Python, one easy way is to use the environment:

```
export URL="${1}"
IFS= read -d '' code << "EOF"
import urllib2, os
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
page = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(os.environ['URL']))
images = page.findAll('img')
for image in images:
    print(image["src"])
EOF
python <(echo "${code}")
```

The changes from your original code:

- The use of `export` when assigning `URL`
- The `import os` in the Python
- The reference to `os.environ['URL']` in the Python.

As for why this approach is preferable -- consider what would happen if you were processing a URL given containing the string `"+__import__('shutil').rmtree('/')+"`. Running

```
page = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(""+__import__('shutil').rmtree('/')+""))
```

...is probably not going to have the effect you intend.